como puedo hacer que me aparezca marcado por defualt la casilla "los calendarios de todos" en el modulo de calendarios?
en el modulo de calendarios del odoo 16 hay una sección como de selección que se llama asistentes, la cual por lo que veo es un campo many2many al modulo de contactos, tiene dos elementos ya establecidos que seria el usuario y otro que dice "los calendarios de todos", sin embargo el primero ya esta seleccionado por default mientras que el segundo no y me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de dejar esa casilla ya marcada de forma permanente, la verdad no se como esta programada esa casilla ya que esa sección es una lista de contactos pero esa casilla no parece ser un contacto, si alguien pudiera ayudarme me seria de mucha ayuda.
